# SQLAlchemy: Parent instance not bound to a session, even though it should be?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is yet another *"Parent instance is not bound to a Session"* question.

I have function that does the following (simplified):

```py
def check_schedules(org):
   # ...
   for user in org.users:
        for schedule in user.schedules:
            schedule._set_minimum_time()
```

Where `org` is an ORM model, `users` is a relationship to `User` model, and `schedules` is a relationship to `Schedule` model

And:

```
class Schedule(Base):
    # ... 
    def _set_minimum_time(self):
        organization_schedule = self.user.organization.schedule
```

`check_schedules` is called in various flows, and succeeds. However in a specific flow, from within a worker's job, it raises the `DetachedInstanceError` error:

```
DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Schedule at 0x7f2900ab3af0> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'user' cannot proceed
```

Do you have any explanation as to why this happens?
The session is a scoped session (created with `autocommit=False` and `autoflush=False`), there are no other threads running, and we can see that the loading of `user` was successfully lazy-loaded in the first loop
so we'd expect it to already be in the session when `schedule` tries to dereference it in the `_set_minimum_time` function.

Python: 3.9.17
SQLAlchemy version: 1.3.24

### UPDATE #1:

Upon debugging, and breaking on `schedule._set_minimum_time()` I can see that `schedule not in db_session`

In fact, `all([schedule not in db_session for schedule in user.schedules])` returns `True`

Still not sure why this happens, but the relationship of `schedules` and `user` is defined as follows:

```py
class User(Base):
  # ..
  schedules = relationship(
        "Schedule",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        passive_deletes=False,
        back_populates="user",
    )
```

and

```py
class Schedule(Base):
  # ..
  user_uuid = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("user.uuid"), nullable=False, index=True)
  user = relationship("User", back_populates="schedules")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investing some time debugging this I was able to pinpoint the issue!

To simplify, the flow that failed did the following:

```py
def flow_that_fails():
    do_something(org)
    check_schedules(org)

def do_something(org):
    # This was some function called prior to check_schedules
    # and internally it also did some calculation with the schedules
    # Specifically it expunged the schedules before doing the calculation
    for user in org.users:
        for schedule in user.schedules:
            # ...
            db_session.expunge(schedule)
            # ...
```

The fact that the schedules were previously expunged made it so that the following time the relationship was iterated in `check_schedules`
it returned the already expunged objects.

So the small reproducer for this issue is essentially:

```py
schedules_uuids = []
for schedule in user.schedules:
    schedules.append(schedule.uuid)
    db_session.expunge(schedule)

for schedule in user.schedules:
    assert schedule not in db_session

for schedule_uuid in user.schedules:
    schedule = db_session.query(Schedule).get(schedule_uuid)
    assert schedule in db_session

for schedule in user.schedules:
    # Even though the objects were re-fetched above using the uuids
    # Going through the relationship still returns the previously expunged
    # objects
    assert schedule not in db_session
```

I'm not a 100% this is the expected behavior, such that the relationship memoizes the expunged objects.

In any case, this wasn't easy to debug 
(The way I found the problem eventually was by reproducing the exception locally and then bisecting the code, removing calls to functions that were suspected to damage the session, until I was able to pinpoint the offending functions and dive into them until I found that offending expunge)

Comment: I've opened a discussion on sqlalchemy's github https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/10110